# Parseing JSON Array with unnamed fields with GSON

Tags: java, json, parsing

So I want to parse flightradar24.com data into a Java program. The data seems to be JSON-ish and thus I am trying to read it using GSONs JSonParser.

Here is a short excerpt of what I try to parse (you can see it in full e.g. in http://arn.data.fr24.com/zones/italy_all.js?callback=pd_callback):

```
pd_callback({"45da286":["4CAAB6",43.5609,12.6837,211,34975,420,"7311","F-LIBP2","B772","EI-ISA",1411143824,"NRT","FCO","AZ785",0,0,"AZA785",0],
"45dae4b":["7809B9",47.5892,15.8256,204,36000,442,"7303","F-LKTB2","A332","B-5921",1411143824,"PVG","FCO","MU787",0,0,"CES787",0],
"45dae73":["76CEF7",47.6238,17.2440,291,36000,428,"0342","F-LKTB1","B77W","9V-SWW",1411143826,"SIN","LHR","SQ318",0,0,"SIA318",0],
"45db3e2":["71BC61",46.0211,10.0549,242,22800,344,"7313","F-LIPE1","B744","HL7461",1411143824,"ICN","MXP","KE927",0,-2176,"KAL927",0],
"full_count":10394,"version":4});
```

Each line in the example above resembles the data of a certain flight at that moment, with id, lat, lon, and so on. I have removed pd_callback(...); and just to try it I removed ""full_count":10394,"version":4" as well. When I try to parse this string to an iterable JSON Object Array, e.g. like this:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
com.google.gson.JsonArray jsa = jsonParser.parse(line).getAsJsonArray();
```

I always get parsing errors. I think one of the problems is that the field names are not given and the syntax might be wrong, but thats actually how flightradar reads the data. In the end, I just want to be able to iterate through each flight and to read each attribute as a primitive to then feed it into my own objects.

Anyone with an idea where the problem is or how I can parse this kind of data conveniently? Any comments appreciated.

Comment: The data isn't an array, it's an object with key-value pairs, where the values are arrays.

Comment: What is the text in the variable line?  What kinds of parsing errors are you getting?

Comment: I took the first line of text and put it into a JSON formatter & validator and received an error then added curly braces around it and it validated.  `{"45da286":["4CAAB6",43.5609,12.6837,211,34975,420,"7311","F-LIBP2","B772","EI-ISA",1411143824,"NRT","FCO","AZ785",0,0,"AZA785",0]}` using [this JSON formatter](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: @RichardChambers - The brace is there -- you just failed to copy it.

Comment: Your problem is that you asked for an array when it's an object.  Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.